# How to make if two div's match to stay hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a simple memory game for my kid to play, I wrote this using jQuery. The body background is a background picture and these divs show and hide parts of the background picture.

I want to make an `if` statement that if these two divs hide when you click on them, that they stay hidden, they don't show again. Can anyone help please?

I want for two div's to stay hidden when they are opened one after another, so when you match 2 boxes they stay visible, here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Igra Memorije</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka2").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka2").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka3").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka3").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka4").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka4").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka5").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka5").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka6").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka7").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka7").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka8").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka8").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka9").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka9").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka10").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka10").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka11").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka12").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka12").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka13").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka13").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka14").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka14").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka15").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka15").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka16").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka17").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka17").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka18").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka18").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka19").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka19").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kocka20").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
$("#kocka20").mouseleave(function() {
$(this).show("slow");
});
});
</script>

<div id="kocka">
</div>
<div id="kocka2">
</div>
<div id="kocka3">
</div>
<div id="kocka4">
</div>
<div id="kocka5">
</div>
<div id="kocka6">
</div>
<div id="kocka7">
</div>
<div id="kocka8">
</div>
<div id="kocka9">
</div>
<div id="kocka10">
</div>
<div id="kocka11">
</div>
<div id="kocka12">
</div>
<div id="kocka13">
</div>
<div id="kocka14">
</div>
<div id="kocka15">
</div>
<div id="kocka16">
</div>
<div id="kocka17">
</div>
<div id="kocka18">
</div>
<div id="kocka19">
</div>
<div id="kocka20">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
body {
background:#934A5F;
background-image:url("https://i.ibb.co/s2wQTrL/slika.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

#kocka {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    margin-left:1100px;
    margin-top:555px;
}

#kocka2 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:872px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#kocka3 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:713px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#kocka4 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:553px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}


#kocka5 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:394px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#kocka6 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:-320px;
}

#kocka7 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:553px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#kocka8 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:713px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#kocka9 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:394px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#kocka10 {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:872px;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#kocka11 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    margin-left:1100px;
    margin-top:-318px;
}

#kocka12 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:711px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}

#kocka13 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:870px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}

#kocka14 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:553px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}

#kocka15 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:394px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}

#kocka16 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    margin-left:80px;
    margin-top:-316px;
}

#kocka17 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:553px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}

#kocka18 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:394px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}

#kocka19 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:711px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}

#kocka20 {
    height:158px;
    width:160px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:870px;
    margin-top:-158px;
}
```

Comment: Not fully sure if that would work, but you could try adding `$(this).css("pointer-events", "none");` once you hide the div, so theoretically with that in place it shouldn't hit the `mouseleave` listener any longer

Comment: Another idea how to design the "game": Why dont you simply use css-grid to have the memory cards all the same size? Requires far less hard coding and would be a way easier approach.